# How to find out if view is loaded from "More" in a navigationController or from main tab?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a UITabBarController with many UIViewControllers resulting with a "More" TabBarItem.

One of those views has some editing functions I'd like to place in the UINavigationBar and I can replace the right and left button items, no problem.  However, there seems to be an issue when you move that view controller where the navigation controller is no longer displayed.  I believe I can solve the issue if I know from where the view is loaded from.

Here is my challenge I need some direction on:

What is the best way to check to see if the selected view is not being presented with the top navigation bar?  Meaning, there is no "< More" on the top.   That way I can display my own Edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any view controller can ask for its `tabBarController`. From there, it can get the tab bar controller's `moreNavigationController`. So now it can ask whether its `parent` is the `moreNavigationController`.

Comment: Looks like this may do the trick...  self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController?.navigationController?.title because I get "More" or nil depending on where it's opened from...

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to check if there is a left bar button item using

`navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem == nil`

or

`navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem == nil`

depending on your hierarchy.

Comment: Looks like < More shows nil as part of the navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem -- I'm trying to find out if that is displayed or not.